# Memory usage in java applications

Tags: java, performance

How to calculate what is the maximum memory needed to run a program in Java? (used by that program)

what i did: I recorded currentMemory value many times in run time, then subtract the minimum value from the maximum value.

```
double currentMemory = (Runtime.getRuntime().totalMemory() -  Runtime.getRuntime().freeMemory())
```

but the results wasn't convinced comparing with the activity monitor (Mac OS)

(1) Is there a better way to do that?
(2) Should I measure the memory before calling garbage collector or after?

thank you for helping.

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27831778/how-to-really-benchmark-the-memory-usage-of-a-java-application?rq=1

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25552/get-os-level-system-information

Answer (score 0):

You could just use jconsole or jvisualvm utilities from the jdk installation folder (e.g. on windows `$JAVA_HOME/bin/jconsole.exe`) to get a nice Visual view of the memory consumption throughout the life of the application. 
They are pretty simple to use and very informative in providing realtime insights into the jvm